# Python error: keyword can't be an expression. print value

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am making a game that has a fake loading screen in the beginning. I am trying to make a gradual elipsys that adds a period every second until there are 3 periods. this is the code I put in:

```
    def intro2():
        print('Loading CapsuleCorp computer'=end)
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('.'=end)
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('.')
        time.sleep(3)
        print ('Welcome to the CapsuleCorp main computer.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('Due to new security issues, we have added a new security system.')
        print ('If you are an employee, we teach you these maditoraly.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('we wipe your mind as an ex-enployee')
```

Then, after running, I get this error:

```
    keyword can't be an expression
```

and it highlights this:

```
    print**(**'Loading CapsuleCorp computer'=end)
```

Comment: What exactly did you want it to print?

Comment: "Loading CapsuleCorp computer.",

Comment: I'm curious about what led you to put `=end` in there.

Comment: Because I was going to put a 
        time.sleep(2)

Comment: so that it would do a gradual '...' overtime

Comment: You were going to put `time.sleep(2)` into a `print()` call, so you tried to accomplish that by adding `=end` to it? And the purpose was to "do" an ellipsis? I suggest you start [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/).

Comment: I am sorry for my wording. I wanted the `time.sleep(2)` function to be on the line below it, and then another print after that that prints a '.', and then to repeat it one more time.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you're trying to do, what kind of attempts you've made, and what you expect to see? We can't extrapolate that from a single poorly-formed `print()` call.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
print('Loading CapsuleCorp computer=', end)
```

Based on your additional comment below, you may be looking for this:

```
print('Loading CapsuleCorp computer', end='')
```

Comment: I tried it, and I got this:   

        NameError: global name 'end' is not defined

Comment: Until you tell us what you expected to see, all we can do is guess.

Comment: In this context, Python is expecting "end" to be a variable that contains a value.

Comment: I am wanting it to use the `time.sleep()` function, but for it not to start a new line.

Comment: It's possible that you were looking for `end=''`, but, like this answer, that's just a guess.

Comment: Did you test it? Is it doing what you want? Because I don't think it will.

Comment: I tested it. It works. It did what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: And it's printing with delays where you expect them to be?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible, because I've tried it from the interactive interpreter and from a saved script, and without the `sys.stdout.flush()` calls it waits 5 seconds and then dumps all the `print()` calls at once.

Comment: Oh, I just tested it outside of IDLE. when I tested it outside of idle, It did what you said it would do.